# How to see textbox entry from one form in another form

Tags: windows, c++-cli

I am trying to pass the `textBox1` value from `Form5` to `Form1`. However it does not seem to remember or see the value when it gets to `Form1`. I want `paf_path` to be what `paf_path2` is.

```
System::Void Form5::button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    System::String^ paf_path2 = textBox1->Text;

    FolderBrowserDialog^ folderBrowserDialog1;
    folderBrowserDialog1 = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::FolderBrowserDialog;
    folderBrowserDialog1->Description = L"Select the directory of your MAF files ";
    folderBrowserDialog1->ShowNewFolderButton = false;

    // Show the FolderBrowserDialog.
    System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1->ShowDialog();
    if (result == ::DialogResult::OK)
    {
        paf_path2 = folderBrowserDialog1->SelectedPath;
    }

    textBox1->Text = paf_path2;
}

System::Void Form5::button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e){
    Form1 ^dos3 = gcnew Form1(this);
    dos3->Show();
    this->Hide();
}

System::Void Form1::button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    System::String^ test = textBox1->Text;

    if (test == "")
    {
        MessageBox::Show("Please enter partial address!");
    }
    else
    {
        Form5^doss = gcnew Form5(this);
        System::String^ paf_path2 = doss->textBox1->Text;
        char* paf_path = (char*) (void*) Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(paf_path2);
```

Comment: Either `(char*) (void*)` is unnecessary and probably just plain wrong, or else I'm *really* glad I don't do C++/CLI.

Comment: You are creating a *new* instance of the Form5 object.  It of course has a different value for the textBox1 member.

Comment: I am so confused, how would I see that textBox1 text value in form1 then? @HansPassant